# grep invert search with context

Tags: unix, shell, sed, grep

**I want to filter out several lines before and after a matching line in a file.**

This will remove the line that I don't want:

```
$ grep -v "line that i don't want"
```

And this will print the 2 lines before and after the line I don't want:

```
$ grep -C 2 "line that i don't want"
```

But when I combine them it does not filter out the 2 lines before and after the line I don't want:

```
# does not remove 2 lines before and after the line I don't want:
$ grep -v -C 2 "line that i don't want"
```

How do I filter out not just the line I don't want, but also the lines before and after it?  I'm guessing `sed` would be better for this...

Edit:  I know this could be done in a few lines of awk/Perl/Python/Ruby/etc, but I want to know if there is a succinct one-liner I could run from the command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
sed 'h;:b;$b;N;N;/PATTERN/{N;d};$b;P;D' inputfile
```

You can vary the number of `N` commands before the pattern to affect the number of lines to delete.

You could programmatically build a string containing the number of `N` commands:

```
C=2 # corresponds to grep -C
N=N
for ((i = 0; i < C - 1; i++)); do N=$N";N"; done
sed "h;:b;\$b;$N;/PATTERN/{N;d};\$b;P;D" inputfile
```

Comment: no, you mean `grep` just cannot do this?! is there a reason? it's counterintuitive for me

Comment: @naxa: When `-C` and `-v` are used together the `-C` includes excluded lines rather than excluding additional lines. Try this: `printf '%s\n' {1..36} | grep --color -C 2 -v '^2.'` and you'll see that 20, 21, 28 and 29 are included rather than 18, 19, 30 and 31 being excluded. The `-C` option is not specified by POSIX, by the way.

Comment: ah I see. thank you very much for your concern and the nice example now in color! I've tried with -A and -B but they work alike -C. They also seem to be 'non-posix' now that I know what I missed to look for.

Comment: I'm having a very hard time understanding what your one-liner sed does command-by-command even with the help of the man pages. I'll probably review later but if it's not too much trouble would you mind breaking it down? I think it would benefit the quality of the answer.

Answer (score 6):

If the lines are all unique you could grep the lines you want to remove into a file, and then use that file to remove the lines from the original, e.g.

```
grep -C 2 "line I don't want" < A.txt > B.txt
grep -f B.txt A.txt
```

Comment: Can one-line this w/o a side file:  `grep -C1 unwanted A.txt | grep -vFf- A.txt` ... this uses `-f-` which reads the 'file' from stdin.   Also, I suggest `-F` for fixed strings.

Comment: Finally, OP is missing `-v`

Answer (score 2):

I solved it with two sequential grep, actually. It seems way more straightforward to me.

```
grep -C "match" yourfile | grep -v -f - yourfile
```

Comment: This solution doesn't always work; see [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20665790/509868) for details.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN{n=2}{a[++i]=$0}
/dont/{
  for(j=1;j<=i-(n+1);j++)print a[j];
  for(o=1;o<=n;o++)getline;
  delete a}
END{for(i in a)print a[i]} ' file
```

Comment: I know you probably already know this since you've got way more XP than me, but you may want to add a little more explanation than just the code segment maybe, addressing the fact that the OP asked for a grep solution, while offering your otherwise very valid and extremely useful AWK solution. Thanks!

Comment: @DermotCanniffe, lol the accepted answer is even more convoluted using sed.

Comment: Quite true. As much as I love sed, I think awk procedures are much easier to explicate. :)

Answer (score -1):

I think @fxm27 has an excellent, bash-y answer.

I would add that you could solve this another way by using egrep if you knew in advance the patterns of the subsequent lines.

```
command | egrep -v "words|from|lines|you|dont|want"
```

That will do an "inclusive OR", meaning that a line that matches *any* of those will be excluded.

Answer (score -2):

**2019 Solution**

This is a simple solution, found elsewhere:

```sh
grep --invert-match "test*"
```

Selects all *not matching* "test*". Super useful and easy to remember!

**(Edit)**

This doesn't completely answer the original question and returns the entire set of lines not matching.

Comment: This solution doesn't remove next and after pattern matching lines.